# Environ's body doesn't allow for making an \item

Tags: lists, environments

As part of a document process/workflow, it's easier to work with environments. However, in some cases the environment contents needs specific formatting. As such, it's convenient to use the [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) to capture the environment `\BODY`, and then use it as needed.

The following elementary implementation doesn't work though:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{HEADING}{%
  \item[\BODY]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \begin{HEADING}
  Heading
  \end{HEADING}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

How can I get around to having `environ`ment `HEADING` process it's `\BODY` as an argument in the expected way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to execute `\item[...]` outside the environment, because it *must* be at the outer level in a list. The reason is that `\item` does `\@item`, which sets `\everypar`; having it in a group would cause every sort of problems.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{HEADING}{%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\THISHEADING\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\item\expandafter[\BODY]%
  }%
  \aftergroup\THISHEADING
}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \begin{HEADING}
  Heading
  \end{HEADING}
  Something to follow
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this with a regular environment and received the same error, so it's not anything that `environ` is doing wrong. Getting around this problem appears to require tricking LaTeX, so take the following with a pinch of salt. To be honest without looking into the source I'm not sure why the extra `\mbox{}` is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{HEADING}{%
  \item[\BODY]%
  \mbox{}% <-- this is important
}

\begin{document}

\section{testing}
some test before
\begin{description}
  \begin{HEADING}
  Heading
  \end{HEADING}
  text
\end{description}
some text after

\section{normal}
some test before
\begin{description}
  \item[Heading]
  text
\end{description}
some text after

\end{document}
```

Comment: Having `\item` inside a group has adverse effects, because `\@item` sets `\everypar`, but when the group it's in ends, the value of `\everypar` is reset to empty. Your `\mbox{}` cures the symptom (the “perhaps a missing `\item`" error), but not the disease.